# Ошибка числа или значения при выгрузке XML из CLOB с размером более 32К

Tags: java, spring, oracle, blob, clob

Собственно есть spring приложение которое вызывает функцию возвращающую xml в clob'е.
Само взаимодействие с базой данных происходит через DAO (java классы генерятся с помощью jooq-codegen). Все работает хорошо ровно до тех пор функция не пытается вернуть clob размером около 32 килобайт. И тогда spring приложение выдает :

> exception 
>   EBUG ReportsDao:130 - jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [begin ? := "WORK"."REPORTS_SERVER"."GETDOCUMENT"("IDNSF" => ?, "TYPEDOCUMENT" => ?); end;]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL:  ошибка числа или значения
>   ORA-06512: на  line 1

C clob'ами меньшего размерами все работает на ура

Собственно вопрос, насколько правильно мое предположение что все дело в размере и как с этим бороться?

PS
В SQL Developer функция возвращает clob большего размера без проблем

Comment: Посмотрите в функцию, что там не так.

Comment: там все так, В SQL Developer функция возвращает clob большего размера без проблем

Comment: Покажите, как вы функцию вызываете в sql-developer и как она вызывается в коде.

Comment: Это вот в developer: select
    Reports_Server.getDiadocDocument(13873715, 'INVOICE') 
from dual

Comment: а как она вызывается в коде вот в самом посте, сам код генерит жук

Comment: В посте не код, а сообшение об ошибке. В sql-developere вы вызываете в запросе. В коде у вас скорее всего возврат в varchar2, а не в clob, max 32K, отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: @0xdbв коде у меня возврат clob:  function getDocument(idnsf number, typeDocument varchar2)  return clob;

Comment: А куда происходит возврат (первый знак "?" после begin)? Я это имел ввиду.

Comment: @0xdb в переменную String

Comment: Уже написал, см. выше. В SQL  нет String, есть varchar.

Comment: @0xdb я думал вы про java код спрашиваете.... в pl/sql я возвращаю clob, а в java он уже засовывает в String

Comment: "в pl/sql я возвращаю clob, а в java он уже засовывает в String" - а между этими двумя событиями, где хранится возвращаемый результат, как вы думаете?

Comment: @0xdb вы хотите сказать что jdbc драйвер трансформирует его в varchar2 прежде чем мне отдать?

Comment: Ну да, пока происходит выполнение pl/sql блока, в нём применяются только ему известные типы данных.

Comment: Интересно, потому что возвращаемое значение в Java определяется как public static final org.jooq.Parameter<java.lang.String> RETURN_VALUE = createParameter("RETURN_VALUE", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.CLOB);

Comment: Вот что [нашёл](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/reference/reference-data-types/data-types-lobs/). Joog явно не поддерживает CLOBs.

Comment: Любые блобы/силобы в коде лучше гонять как массив байтов. Просто совет.

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки: функция пытается вернуть `CLOB` размером более 32 KB в переменную типа `VARCHAR2`, которая может вместить макс. 32 КB данных.

Из актульной [офф. документации jOOQ 3.11](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/reference/reference-data-types/data-types-lobs/):

> Hence, **jOOQ currently doesn't explicitly support JDBC BLOB and CLOB data types**. If you use any of these data types in your database, jOOQ will map them to byte[] and String instead. In simple cases (small data), this simplification is sufficient. **In more sophisticated cases, you may have to bypass jOOQ, in order to deal with these data types and their respective resources**.

jOOQ пока не поддерживает типы данных `BLOB` и `CLOB`. По умолчанию для них будут использованы `byte[]` и `String` соответственно. В особых случаях, необходимо отказаться от использования jOOQ для работы с этими типами данных.

---

В связанной [теме на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642421/b-clob-handling-in-jooq) для Spring предложено использовать `JdbcTemplate` и следующий код для определения обработчика больших объектов:

```
public static LobHandler getAppropriateLobHandler(Factory factory) {
    LobHandler lobHandler = null;
    switch( factory.getDialect() ) {
        case ORACLE: lobHandler = new OracleLobHandler(); break;
        default: lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler(); break;
    }
    return lobHandler;
}
```

Так же, будет полезно ознакомится с дискуссией по предложеному решнию [на этом гугле-канале](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jooq-user/TtVFLzXc9RA).